# Data binding fails for Chart control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, charts

I am using asp chart control to display some values from database on chart. However, I face the following error, where I have specified by single-line commenting.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string query = "select distinct name from tblDars";
            DataTable dt = GetData(query);
            ddlSubject.DataSource = dt;
            ddlSubject.DataTextField = "tblDars";
            ddlSubject.DataValueField = "tblDars";
            //ddlSubject.DataBind();
            ddlSubject.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));
        }
    }
```

the markup for the control is as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubject" runat="server"
onselectedindexchanged="ddlSubjectChanged" AutoPostBack = "true">
</asp:DropDownList><hr />
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="400px" Visible = "false">
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title ShadowOffset="3" Name="Items" />
    </Titles>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Top" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Row" />
    </Legends>
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="درس" />
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderWidth="0" />
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

There are two other functions that I am using within the class too;
, one for event handling, the other for doing database jobs;  they are shown below:

```
 protected void ddlSubjectChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Chart1.Visible = ddlSubject.SelectedValue != "";
        //string query = string.Format("select shipcity, count(orderid) from orders where shipcountry = '{0}' group by shipcity", ddlSubject.SelectedValue);
        string query = string.Format("select Name, count (id) from tblDars where Name='{0}' group by Name", ddlSubject.SelectedValue);
        DataTable dt = GetData(query);
        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        int[] y = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
        }
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
        Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
    }

        private static DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        String constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
```

Everything seems OK I don't know what the error rises from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning "name" column from db but you're setting Invalid column names

Specify valid columns in DataTextField and DataValueField.

```
ddlSubject.DataTextField = "name";
 ddlSubject.DataValueField = "name";
```